# Node.JS: Why is my connection to localhost:3000 refused?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a student going into back-end development for the first time and are trying to learn Node.JS. I downloaded a pdf book about Node.JS from sitepoint called: "Jumpstart Node.JS". In following the instructions to set up the server on the command line, install the dependencies, and navigate to localhost:3000, i got nothing except the following message: "Connection refused: localhost:3000", Can somebody please tell me what might have went wrong and how to fix it?

**Edit1:**
The instructions i followed is about setting up a node.js server using the Node command line, thus no code, simply cmd commands, however, here is a quick summary of the process i followed:

1. Created an account on MongoLabs and then a database using the free pricing plan.
2. Installed *express* using the command: **npm install -g express@.2.5.8**.
3. Created an applications with default options using this command: **express authentication**.
4. modified the **package.json** file in system32
5. installed the dependencies by typing **cd authentication**, hitting enter, and then typing the command: **npm install**
6. Typed **node app** and hit enter.
   According to the instructions i should have seen a message: "Welcome to express" but instead got the error message.

Comment: We have no idea without at least _some_ code.

Comment: and also the command line sequence you used to start node, for example `node start`. You *did* run that, right?

Comment: Connection refused though? It's possible. This is the error message in chrome when the server isn't running: *This site can’t be reached \n localhost refused to connect.* Which browser and what error message more exactly?

Comment: you should consider adding more information

Comment: no i didn't the instructions i received in the book didn't tell me that, now i'm unable to however since the the express server is in development mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In following the instructions to set up the server on the command line, install the dependencies, and navigate to localhost:3000

It seems that you didn't start the server.

Somewhere between installing the dependencies and navigating to the URL you need to actually start the server if you want it to serve the request.

Answer (score 0):

Check that there is no copy of the server running in the background, or that another app is using the port currently.
(Your firewall show allow you to see which app has been allocated to that port)
Because nodejs requires it to be the only app on that port running on your computer.

Also try a different port maybe?